# Multiple query results

Tags: database, ms-access

I am currently running a query in MS Access where i am searching for matching fields, the only problem is is that it is returning  multiple fields which are all identical, is there anyway of limiting the results if the are identical?

Comment: You could use `SELECT DISTINCT` to get only rows that differ in at least one field value, but it would help if you gave us some sample code and sample data to see what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `DISTINCT`.

Try something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  table.*
FROM table
```

Comment: i decided just to run a duplicate query along side the first one, could you see any problem in doing this?